# What is the relation between 2d Fourier Transform and Plane Waves?

Tags: fourier-analysis, physics, fourier-transform, electromagnetism

I'm not understanding how the two was related, but I was told that the 2d Fourier Transform decomposes an electromagnetic signal into plane waves. This, however, I am not understanding. I thought it would just convert the electromagnetic signal into 2d sinusoids.

Can somebody elaborate on their relationship because I can only visualize it a decomposition of a 3d signals as sinusoids and not planes?

Comment: See if [this](http://cns-alumni.bu.edu/~slehar/fourier/fourier.html) can help you.

Comment: In two dimensions, a scalar plane wave has the form $F(k_x,k_y)e^{i(k_xx+k_yy)}$.  Now, the superposition of such components over all $k_x$ and $k_y$ is a Fourier integral.

Comment: @MarkViola I'm not quite understanding. This plane wave has no appearance of a sinusoid at all. It is only sinusoidal in the direction of propagation, but aren't we only looking at a snapshot of the plane at one point.

Comment: The direction of the wave is $\hat x k_x+\hat y k_y$ and the wave is clearly "sinusoidal" inasmuch as the complex exponential $e^{i(\vec k\cdot \vec \rho-\omega t)}=\cos(\vec k\cdot \vec \rho-\omega t)+i \sin(\vec k\cdot \vec \rho-\omega t)$.

Comment: @MarkViola ok but I'm confused then. Is the plane wave itself perpendicular or parallel to the signal being decomposed?

Comment: $k_x x + k_y y$ is constant in any direction $(x,y)$ that is perpendicular to the vector $(k_x,k_y)$, and it changes most quickly in the direction of the vector $(k_x,k_y)$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Sorry, not sure what those variables mean. Is the plane wave orthogonal to, or parallel to the signal we are decomposing?

Comment: To answer your last comment, we would need to have an idea of what the "direction" of the plane wave is and what the "direction" of the signal is. To me, both of these appear to be 3D structures and it is not clear to me why you would consider either of them to be pointing in a particular direction.

Comment: @DavidK Actually, the field is decomposed into an electric field, so the wave must be parallel to the plane which we are decomposing the signal (if you consider it to be a 2d graph with density rather than a 3d graph) Right? I think I understand now

Comment: I think I misread the comment. The plane waves mentioned earlier do have a clear direction in the plane. But the Fourier transform could add together an infinite number of these in many different directions, so they might compose a signal that has no particular direction at all.